# spark sql :- Find out the Id, Name, Salary of the people whose planned pension is more than 20% of the salary

Tags: sql, mysqli, apache-spark-sql

Using an SQL query, I am trying to extract the Id, Name, and Salary of the records which have planned pension more than 20% of the salary.

Here is my SQL query:

```
sqlContext.sql("""select Id,Name,Salary from work where Pension >= Salary/20*100 order by Id asc""").show()
```

And, here is the table which my SQL query is accessing:

```
[
    Row(Id=1, Name=u'Anu', Mail=u'Anu1@gmail.cpm', Age=23, Salary=15000, Pension=5000),
    Row(Id=6, Name=u'Teja', Mail=u'Teja6@gmail.com', Age=38, Salary=20000, Pension=2000),
    Row(Id=9, Name=u'Arun', Mail=u'Arun9@gmail.com', Age=27, Salary=50000, Pension=3000),
    Row(Id=5, Name=u'Ramu', Mail=u'Ramu5@gmail.com', Age=35, Salary=40000, Pension=3000),
    Row(Id=3, Name=u'Geetha', Mail=u'Geetha3@gmail.com', Age=31, Salary=24000, Pension=4000),
    Row(Id=2, Name=u'Archana', Mail=u'Archana2@gmail.com', Age=30, Salary=20000, Pension=2000),
    Row(Id=10, Name=u'Reka', Mail=u'Reka10@gmail.com', Age=30, Salary=20000, Pension=4000),
    Row(Id=4, Name=u'Ramesh', Mail=u'Ramesh4@gmail.com', Age=32, Salary=30000, Pension=3000),
    Row(Id=8, Name=u'Ezhil', Mail=u'Ezhil8@gmail.com', Age=28, Salary=40000, Pension=4000),
    Row(Id=7, Name=u'Murali', Mail=u'Murali7@gmail.com', Age=39, Salary=20000, Pension=1000)
]
```

Comment: Try to add More details Information for get Fast Answer .

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change formula. `20%` means divide by 5 of that number.
so your query may looks like as follow.

```
SELECT id, name, salary FROM `work` WHERE pension >= (salary / 5) order by Id ASC
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the answer.